Excel list of values where data matches across multiple rows
I have data (40000+ rows) that is in format like (including empty rows)

I want to get list of 'all' Model where Model Type = Interest and corresponding Marge (sometimes after 2 rows and sometimes after 3 rows) = Yes.
So in this example it should return A, D
Tried lots of combination of Filter, XMatch etc.. Transforming data (row to column is not a valid option due to size of data and variable number of rows in each section) Any suggestions.
real data example:


There is no additional screenshot btw as per your edit summary!

@MayukhBhattacharya added now, earlier it had data that i did not want to share ..so deleted it

You could try using the following as well, and this should be working even if the Marge is sometimes after 2 or 3 rows:


Option One:
=LET(
     _Data, WRAPCOLS(FILTER(C2:C26,1-ISNA(XMATCH(B2:B26,{"Model","ModelType","Marge"}))),3),
     FILTER(TAKE(_Data,1),(INDEX(_Data,2)="Interest")*(INDEX(_Data,3)="Yes"),""))


Or, Option Two:
=LET(
     _Data, WRAPROWS(FILTER(C2:C26,1-ISNA(XMATCH(B2:B26,{"Model","ModelType","Marge"}))),3),
     FILTER(TAKE(_Data,,1), (INDEX(_Data,,2)="Interest")*(INDEX(_Data,,3)="Yes"),""))


Step By Step Method: --> Try changing the last variable to the other variables to understand how the above formulas work. The logic is same. First, find the positions of the each attributes, once found check whether it returns a number or not, if it does, extract those using FILTER() function, next use either WRAPCOLS() or WRAPROWS(), finally using FILTER() to get the output based on the specific columns criteria. Simple to understand and easy to debug.



=LET(
     _Position, XMATCH(B2:B26,{"Model","ModelType","Marge"}),
     _Include, 1-ISNA(_Position),
     _Extract, FILTER(C2:C26,_Include,""),
     _Wrap, WRAPROWS(_Extract,3),
     _Output, FILTER(TAKE(_Wrap,,1),(INDEX(_Wrap,,2)="Interest")*(INDEX(_Wrap,,3)="Yes"),""),
     _Output)


Updated Solution based on OPs new updated screenshot:


=LET(
     _Extract, WRAPROWS(FILTER(F2:F28,(1-ISNA(XMATCH(E2:E28,{"Model","ModelType","Marge"})))*(B2:B28="Nil")*(MAP(D2:D28,E2:E28,LAMBDA(a,b, COUNTIFS(a:D2,a,b:E2,b))))=1),3),
     FILTER(TAKE(_Extract,,1),(INDEX(_Extract,,2)="Rating Base")*(INDEX(_Extract,,3)="Row/Column"),""))


wow! this is so so helpful.. I am trying to mimic it to my real example with your example ...my simplified appears to be too simple

I tried hard to understand this part of the formula =MAP(D2:D28,E2:E28,LAMBDA(a,b, COUNTIFS(a:D2,a,b:E2,b))) (the countifs part with a:D2 part) and i can't wrap my head around it ..manually it translates to =COUNTIFS(D2:D28:D2,D2:D28,E2:E28:E2,E2:E28) ..what is this first part D2:D28:D2

@Ani it translate to : =COUNTIFS(D$2:D2,D2,E$2:E2,E2) running totals. Try placing this in a different cell: =MAP(D2:D28,E2:E28,LAMBDA(a,b, COUNTIFS(a:D2,a,b:E2,b)))

Thank you all clear. Thank you so much for your patience. Its completely new way of excel for me. Let me see if I can extend this further to also return Segment ID

Followup Q I extended the formula to include column D as LET(
_Extract, WRAPROWS(LET(c, CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(D2:F28,(1-ISNA(XMATCH(E2:E28,{"Model","ModelType","Marge"})))(B2:B28="Nil")(MAP(D2:D28, E2:E28,LAMBDA(a,b,COUNTIFS(a:D2,a,b:E2,b))))=1),1,3), TAKE(c,,1)&"."&TAKE(c,,-1)),3),
FILTER(TAKE(_Extract,,1),
(    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rating Base", INDEX(_Extract,,2)))  )*(    ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Row/Column", INDEX(_Extract,,3)))
),"")
)
.Is this most optimal way? Would you have done it differently?

@Ani understood, you could try using one of the followings: 1. =LET(      _SegmentID, D2:D28,      _Property, E2:E28,      _Values, F2:F28,      _RollingCounts, MAP(_SegmentID,_Property,LAMBDA(r,c,COUNTIFS(D2:r,r,E2:c,c))),      _Extract, WRAPROWS(FILTER(_SegmentID&"."&_Values,(B2:B28="Nil")*(1-ISNA(XMATCH(_Property,{"Model","ModelType","Marge"})))*_RollingCounts,""),3),      FILTER(TAKE(_Extract,,1),BYROW(1-ISERR(FIND({"Rating Base","Row/Column"},TAKE(_Extract,,-2))),AND)))

@Ani or 2. =LET(      _SegmentID, D2:D28,      _Property, E2:E28,      _Values, F2:F28,      _RollingCounts, MAP(_SegmentID,_Property,LAMBDA(r,c,COUNTIFS(D2:r,r,E2:c,c))),      _Extract, WRAPROWS(FILTER(_SegmentID&"."&_Values,(B2:B28="Nil")*(1-ISNA(XMATCH(_Property,{"Model","ModelType","Marge"})))*_RollingCounts,""),3),      FILTER(TAKE(_Extract,,1),MMULT(1-ISERR(FIND({"Rating Base","Row/Column"},TAKE(_Extract,,-2))),{1;1})>1))

Thank you. Love this new solution...its easy to read and understand. Really appreciate your help

@Ani just for information, the first one uses BYROW() --> without LAMBDA() construct, i am not sure whether you have the access to Office Insiders or not, if not then add the LAMBDA() construct, i am sure you will be able to do it.

thats why i was getting errors..i changed it array multiplication like... ( ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Rating Base", INDEX(_Extract,,2))) )*( ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Row/Column", INDEX(_Extract,,3))) )

@Ani this is what you need to do: =LET(      _SegmentID, D2:D28,      _Property, E2:E28,      _Values, F2:F28,      _RollingCounts, MAP(_SegmentID,_Property,LAMBDA(r,c,COUNTIFS(D2:r,r,E2:c,c))),      _Extract, WRAPROWS(FILTER(_SegmentID&"."&_Values,(B2:B28="Nil")*(1-ISNA(XMATCH(_Property,{"Model","ModelType","Marge"})))*_RollingCounts,""),3),      FILTER(TAKE(_Extract,,1),BYROW(1-ISERR(FIND({"Rating Base","Row/Column"},TAKE(_Extract,,-2))),LAMBDA(ε,AND(ε)))))

Using Ids as returns from matches, try this function using variables,
header, data, id_col_name, match_attr_name, match_val_name, match_attr_1, match_val_1, match_attr_2, match_val_2, return_attr_name
for the initial sample:
(A1:C1, A2:C100, "id", "attribute", "value", "ModelType", "Interest", "Marge", "Yes", "Model")
with values for the latest data set:
(A1:E1, A2:E100, C1, D1, E1, M6, N6, M7, N7, "Model")
=LAMBDA(
    header,
    data,
    id_col_name,
    match_attr_name,
    match_val_name,
    match_attr_1,
    match_val_1,
    match_attr_2,
    match_val_2,
    return_attr_name,
    LET(
        comment_1, "Remove blanks",
        data, FILTER(data, INDEX(data, 0, XMATCH(id_col_name, header)) <> ""),
        comment_2, "Get range(column_header(name)), range defaults to data",
        data_col, LAMBDA(name, [d],
            LET(d, IF(ISOMITTED(d), data, d), INDEX(d, 0, XMATCH(name, header)))
        ),
        id, LAMBDA([d], IF(ISOMITTED(d), data_col(id_col_name), data_col(id_col_name, d))),
        attr, data_col(match_attr_name),
        val, data_col(match_val_name),
        match_1_ids, FILTER(id(), (attr = match_attr_1) * (val = match_val_1), "No matches"),
        match_2_ids, FILTER(id(), (attr = match_attr_2) * (val = match_val_2), "No matches"),
        FILTER(
            val,
            (attr = return_attr_name) *
                ISNUMBER(
                    XMATCH(
                        id(),
                        FILTER(
                            match_1_ids,
                            ISNUMBER(XMATCH(match_1_ids, match_2_ids)),
                            "No matches"
                        )
                    )
                ),
            "No matches"
        )
    )
)(A1:E1, A2:E100, C1, D1, E1, M6, N6, M7, N7, "Model")



thank you for your effort for this solution and the explanation. I am using Mayukh's solution finally cause I have already spent debugging and understanding it

The way you have written this question makes me think that you meant to say that the blocks of 4 rows can have their respective attributes jumbled up. I tried to represent this in the below example:

Formula in E2:
=TOCOL(LET(a,A2:A25,b,B2:B25,c,C2:C25,MAP(UNIQUE(a),LAMBDA(x,IFS(COUNTIFS(a,x,b,"ModelType",c,"Interest")COUNTIFS(a,x,b,"Marge",c,"Yes"),FILTER(c,(a=x)(b="Model")))))),3)

oh wow! I am trying to wrap my head around the formula (looks like I will take more time to understand than the time you took to write). They are unfortunately not in groups of 4. The maximum block size I see in data is 37 rows

@Ani, ammended!

@JvdV the updated formula does not seem to work
